# Do we have an ethical liability or not on this site?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

There is a more than one month old [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35917/are-both-pleasure-experienced-by-a-rapist-and-the-pain-by-the-victim-the-result) on this site which is ripping apart the ethical liability/morality of this site.

It's the case of the weird victim-blaming with religious backing. It did get 10 downvotes but failed to get close it seems.

But my question is should we entertain such questions?

As it seems OP is asking for religious-based backing for rape, which is purely disgusting.

And if we want to close it then which reason?

I am not asking from user perspective like [this meta](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/should-users-on-this-forum-declare-they-will-act-on-their-beliefs) but want to know from site point of view.

Comment: I remember seeing close votes.  But close votes time period went off as no 5 users made it.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti I have started the close vote chain again, let's see

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should users on this forum declare they will act on their beliefs?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/should-users-on-this-forum-declare-they-will-act-on-their-beliefs)

Comment: Such content should not be allowed / entertained as we aren't aware of the readers / OPs understanding by reading others' opinions (answers or comments). It is better to remove such content, IMO. request to close asap.

Comment: @mods Please take action.

Comment: I think the downvoters here and the upvoters there had never seen these posts neither from a human perspective nor from our religion perspective. The last point of that question says **simply using up the punya already in his account?** uff!

Comment: @KrishnaShweta at least the question is closed now for god sake.

Comment: @AnkitSharma surprised to see three downvotes. Certainly i am out of words to express my anger on this downvoters!

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti I don't even understand what to make put of those DVs.

Comment: More discussion posts = more unanswered questions on meta. Your question may remain unanswered.

Comment: I've tried to fix the issue by replacing the rude/offensive example by general one.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā I don't think there will be a general example for such questions. The question stands offensive no matter how much edition is done. If you have other opinion on this, please share your thoughts. IMO, lets not discuss on the stuff which stands wrong. FYI, the OP wants to know as an assurance. Look out his other questions as well.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā this edit was more like let's not blame rape victim but every victim.

Comment: @Mr_Green ok. Let me check.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes, this may be a question want to know how the law of karma works in this example.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā intention is pretty clear, which can't be covered behind karma. It's clearly justifying rape based on victim's past life karma.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā FYI, even after your edit, the question has now been deleted by 3 users.

Comment: @sv. because SE works by community.

Comment: Sure, but SE mods can also override community decisions. All it takes is five users to close a question they don't like. 3 users to silently delete it. Easy to rig the system. @AnkitSharma

Comment: @sv. So you want mods to easily ignore community conscious so that they can bring back a question about justifying rape which you unexpectedly like.

Comment: @sv. I bring a meta and after getting an answer with positive score I did that, not like you who is pinging a mod friend to overturn community for personal favours.

Comment: First off, my above comment is directed at a mod, not you. And your meta post is only talking about closure, not deletion. Both are two different things. Since deletion happens silently I'm bringing it to the attention of a mod who already clarified his position above. To repeat his words: "Yes, this may be a question want to know how the law of karma works in this example". "not like you who is pinging a mod friend" - LOL, what is 'mod friend' supposed to mean? I see you and couple of "your friends" also pinging the mod on main and meta site to question his recent edits. I'm doing the same.

Comment: 'about justifying rape which you unexpectedly like' - If you paid any attention, I have explained my reasons on why I thought the question is a valid one in the comments under the original question. Beyond that you and your friends can imagine whatever you want. 4 downvotes on this meta question and 5 upvotes on the main question shows there are others who don't like your idea but are not willing to speak up because they are worried they will also be labeled as "justifying rape" as you are doing with me.

Comment: @sv. First I am not part of ”group of five” or any ”sect gangs”. Not sure about you so before accusing get a fact check. Second yes if you support of justifying rape I will surely come after you or your ”gang”. Have a good day ‍♂️

Comment: @AnkitSharma Supporting a question about how karma works in the case of rape is not same as justifying rape. It is you who needs to check facts before accusing others of justifying rape.

Comment: @sv.  You can stop pinging me if you want but we have to agree to disagree, as for you someone wants justification of rape is normal for you and unethical for me.

Comment: @Ankit you are right. See the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's not allow to back any such illegal activities, when asked for assurance, by giving explanation from our scriptures. It is better to immediately close such posts as off-topic.

If we are discussing on such stuff then definitely there will be answers/comments with both positive and negative. And we don't know what points the users are grasping. Lets avoid any possibility of encouraging illegal activities as much as possible.

#### Conclusion

Discussion on current illegal activities for assurance must be off-topic.

Comment: 'Discussion on current illegal activities' - I'm just curious, do you consider the practice of Sati illegal?

Comment: Ofcouse, If a person is asking questions like "Why shouldn't we follow sati now?" or "What is the actual procedure to perform Sati?" will definitely mark it as off-topic.

Comment: ^ The above questions are clearly encouraging which is currently illegal.

Comment: @sv. yes sati is illegal , so does rape and murder

Comment: @sv. Do check my comments in [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51782126#51782126).

Comment: What you two are proposing is censorship. As I've stated in my answer other SE sites don't like censorship. We should adopt the same policy here. This is a Q&A site _about_ Hinduism and not a site maintained by Hindus for Hindus. If this site wants to attract users that write quality answers, other than adhering to the Code of Conduct, we shouldn't be doing censorship of any kind. Think coolly without getting emotional.

Comment: @AnkitSharma What you are forgetting is, Sati was once legal in India. There are many answers here that still support Sati using scriptures. See [example1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35290) and [example 2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15395). It doesn't mean people will start Sati again after reading those answers. We need to keep emotion out when making site policies.

Comment: Re: your chat comment, "My view lets keep it Q&A but with rich consideration of documenting our religion in the best possible way" - This is a Q&A site, main focus being answering OP's doubts/questions. So I don't understand what you mean by "documenting our religion in the best possible way" - there are questions and there are answers to those questions, we are not a replacement to Wikipedia on Hinduism.

Comment: @sv. if you forgetting we are talking about **RAPE** here which was never legal. You bring sati out of nowhere but but asker clearly trying to justify rape and you want us to support him for some reason I am not understanding,

Comment: @AnkitSharma "if you forgetting we are talking about RAPE here which was never legal" - sorry to disappoint you, we once had two forms of "marriage" called, Rakshasa and Paishacha as discussed under [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19466) post. Now I can only imagine what else went on during these "marriages."

Comment: "You bring sati out of nowhere" - not out of nowhere, this answer is specifically talking about "current illegal activities" and Sati is currently illegal. Does it mean we want to avoid any and all discussions on Sati because some crazy user now wants to justify and commit Sati after reading a post here?! Anyway, I'm done debating on this topic with you two. One [mod has voted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gapk.png) to leave the question open in its original form. Another mod edits and remove 'rape'...still doesn't make you happy. Good luck with your censorship efforts on the site. @AnkitSharma

Comment: @sv. I hope you can use this argument in Indian court :D

Comment: @sv. I am not saying we should not discuss rape or sati. I am saying we should mark the posts off topic if it is for example asking for assurance on rape or sati (when intentions are clear, why to support?). Other than this context, they(rape or sati or any illegal stuff) are welcome. Also, I don't mean to document the Hinduism as wikipedia does - I don't think wiki is even near to what we are building here in Q&A from genuine scriptural references.

Comment: Also, lets not follow strictly what other SE sites are following, as we are community members we can come up with our own finalized norms and standards. Positively, lets be our site as example to other SE sites but not the opposite.

Comment: @mods do please not vote to reopen such posts without getting a finalized result from this discussion. If you feel otherwise, do please share your thoughts but don't act without finalizing this discussion.

Comment: @AnkitSharma This site is not answerable to Indian courts. Besides, the question is a scholarly one about karma theory, OP is not asking how to get away with rape. It is you who is assigning a hidden intent to OP. When a court looks at it, I'm pretty sure they'll look at the words as written instead of searching for hidden meanings.

Comment: @sv. there are no hidden words, it's clearout justifying rape.

Comment: @sv *"we once had two forms of "marriage" called, Rakshasa and Paishacha"* - This is why people without austerity should not read scriptures. These two forms of marriage are listed as a table of contents, not as a recommendation. Imagine if a book listed the types of sex -  husband-wife, pre-marital, adultery, rape etc. Will you now say the book is promoting promiscuity ? Out of 8 marriages, only first 4 are recommended. 2 others are not recommended, but not prohibited for Kshatriyas (Kings). The last 2 are prohibited for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

(After 3rd revision) Both sides were seeming to be right.

Side 1) Those who were thinking that question is fine as in understanding law of Karma.
Side 2) Those who were thinking that question is faulty and offensive as explained in question.

Initially I tried to salvage the question by replacing offensive example illustrated in the question thinking that it may be the case that questioner is confused and is trying to understand the law of Karma, a good answer can clear the confusion.

But after critically thinking from both the sides again, I got that **the motive behind posting question is not looking like a try to understand the law of Karma. The motive does sound of intentionally justifying the crime to be in line of law of Karma.**

We know that everything we experience is the result of our Karma but at the same time, what we are doing is purely in our hands. If the motive of questioner was to understand the law of Karma, *the question should not have be framed in the way it was.*

Thus it is the **right decision to close and delete the question**. This type of ambiguous questions may take some time before direct deletion due to possible delay (by community/users/mods) in detection of ill motive unlike obvious rude/offensive questions which usually gets purged quickly. Flag this type of question as rude/offensive or better as custom flag explaining the problem with the question. We'll find a way to remove it.

Comment: FYI, [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5081) has no problem accepting the same question. Please check with @PhilipKlöcking and other mods in TL why they disagree with you on this. IMO, downvoting a question is fine but deleting a question is censorship. I think mods should try to uphold SE policy instead of succumbing to majoritarianism. One of the mods here [has already voted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gapk.png) to keep the question open in its original form. I don't know his reasons for not speaking up.

Comment: @sv. Different sites have different mindset.

Answer (score -4):

No, since the site doesn't judge its users or dictate their views, it has no moral responsibility towards how content posted on this site is used by OP and others.

One user [said](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1074) the following on a similar post about controversial answers and I think the same applies to controversial questions like the one you linked.

> I'd finish by saying that it's the internet - and what you're asking is unenforceable. I try to give answers in good faith but it isn't necessarily what I believe in - just what I think is the best answer, referencing what seems appropriate to the question asked. **If something's clearly offensive we have other methods - like flags.**

This has been already stated many times on this site but I will repeat it here: **If one doesn't like a question, they can simply downvote and move on.**

Trying to close valid objective questions somehow just because you don't like them is censorship and against the principles of SE.

> *As it seems OP is asking for religious-based backing for rape, which is purely disgusting*...

That's just *your* personal opinion. OP makes a lengthy argument in the question but you choose to ignore all that and hang on to just one potential problem with the question that, what if someone writes an answer defending rape using the karma theory. And you want to censor such answers. Worse still some users are even downvoting the only answer posted in an effort to delete both the question and answer from the site.

As another CM [says](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1596) on a different post here, always assume best intentions of OP and don't jump to conclusions. She's probably referring to these posts on Parenting SE:

- [Closing Questions That Raise Issues You Disagree With](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94/closing-questions-that-raise-issues-you-disagree-with)
- [Is it acceptable for answers to suggest physical violence?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/619/is-it-acceptable-for-answers-to-suggest-physical-violence)
- [What should we advise when one disagrees with the premise of a question?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/what-should-we-advise-when-one-disagrees-with-the-premise-of-a-question)

Hopefully, users here can learn a thing or two about close-voting from these posts.