# Discussion about the need of a "Controversial post" banner

Tags: discussion, status-completed

As the community mod pointed out [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2207/93) that they can help us get the controversial post banner if the community thinks we need one. Please discuss here and feel free to show agree/disagree by voting this post.

> If Hinduism SE wants to have this feature on, you need to get a community consensus on having this feature and the text in the box. I think the first good step would be holding a meta discussion about it.

Also, please discuss the text content in the banner. Here is the banner [used at IPS](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/16620/32141)

> Controversial Post — You may use comments ONLY to suggest improvements. You may use answers ONLY to provide a solution to the specific question asked below. Moderators will remove debates, arguments or opinions without notice.

Comment: `+1` as I can't vote ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: let others vote up. ;-)

Comment: I have added the tag here, Please flag the post when the changes have to be done in the post and give the reference of the comment where discussion happened. Flagging comment is not much helping because a flagged comment either has to be deleted or the flag itself has to be declined.

Comment: I don't see a need for this yet. Maybe I will in future. As long as a scripture says something, and the correct meaning/translation is provided, that's all there is to it. Whether people of current day and age like it or not is no barometer of controversial-ity. After all, there are many ills plaguing society today that are caused by not conforming to shastras, so mentioning the remedy is paramount.

Comment: @mar That banner is no harm in any sense. It is only for educational purpose. We can still discuss in-scope things.

Comment: I see no point for having such a banner. If anything it will backfire. Controversial is a broad term, and the availability of such a banner will result in members flagging each and every post as controversial (even if the same has scriptural support).

Comment: "*You may use answers ONLY to provide a solution to the specific question asked below. *" — Isn't that true in general, or is Hinduism.SE different from most other SE sites in that respect?

Comment: @RayButterworth I didn't understand how that statement is relevant to this post. FYI, we were trying to understand here whether the explicit controversial banner is required for this site or not.

Comment: @Mr_Green, I'm new to this site, but on the others I'm familiar with it's generally understood that *all* answers should *always* address the question and nothing else.  But this suggestion is speaking as if on this site the rule should apply only to special cases.

Comment: @RayButterworth The special case is discussing controversial stuff like hurting the beliefs of a group or current legalities or even general understanding. Though we can still discuss the controversial stuff it is just to remind the people visiting the post that the discussion here is strictly moderated to not entertain any off-topic going discussions which obviously will be more controversial. This in my opinion is required to diffuse the situation beforehand by making the readers more cautious and well aware before reading or posting anything on that page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature was enabled on the site. Thanks to everyone who've participated in the discussion.

[image]