# Can challenges to incendiary, hurtful material (largely from the past) be fast-tracked?

Tags: support, feature-request

Lately controversial material is being managed better, with moderators stepping in early.

But from the early days of HSE there has been some really hurtful material (to some Hindus) posted, unsupported by scripture.

I'd like to challenge these one-by-one and ask moderators to remove them if unsupported by scripture.

Their presence severely takes away from the quality of the site.

And also, scripturally supported but controversial material needs a label, like Twitter uses "this material could be hurtful to some viewers"

Comment: Add link of those answers as well in question body. That way it'll be easy to navigate to such answers.

Comment: Thanks @thelittlenaruto.  I was thinking challenging them one by one (there might be counter-responses).  At least some posts are so outrageous that challenges to them need to stand by themselves.

Comment: Uhm? if the answers are unsupported by scripture and hurtful to Hindus, I think should be fine to add them in question body.

Comment: Yes _ I just meant one question/answer  or a few questions/answers per challenge.  IT will take some work searching through 12000 plus q/A s @thelittlenaruto

Comment: @Carmen Did OP say that? :-)

Comment: you find that amusing,  @TheLittleNaruto?  Is it part of a moderator's duties to mock posters?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - "scripturally supported but controversial material needs a label," <----- yep .

Comment: @Carmensandiego Oh Guess that went unnoticed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

The [controversial banner is in progress](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2209/93). Once it arrives, anyone can vote/flag to mark a post as controversial. I don't think there is a need to raise meta posts for each such post.

If anyone finds such questions till then, better to bring to mods' notice with one single post than multiple posts.