# Asking a question which is factual but may disturb the faith of Hindus?

Tags: discussion, support

Manu Smruti says,

> satyam bruyat priyam bruyat na
> bruyat satyam apriyam
> priyam ca nanrutam bruyat
> esha dharmah sanatanah
>
> Speak the truth, speak pleasantly, Do not speak the truth in an
> unpleasant manner Even if pleasant, do not speak untruth, This is the
> path of eternal righteousness

But in the Sanskrit work Kiraataarjuneeyam of Mahakavi Bharavi there is a statement :

> नहि प्रियं वक्तुमिच्छन्ति मृषा हितैषिणः
>
> Nahi priyam vaktumichchhanti mrishaa hitaishinah
>
> Those who mean well for others do not want to please them by false
> praise.

Also the Mundaka Upanishad 3.1.6. says

> सत्यमेव जयते नानृतं
> सत्येन पन्था विततो देवयानः ।
>
> Truth alone triumphs; not falsehood. Through truth the divine path is
> spread out

---

Now this is very confusing. I have some questions which are more of a rational and factual bent which point out certian inconsistencies and may falsify currently held believes of many Hindus.

I don't know whether to ask them or not. Should questions which try to seek factual truth be asked even if it may disturb faith of thr religious Hindus?

Comment: like what questions?

Comment: You mean something like this [Discussion about the need of a "Controversial post" banner](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2209/3500) ?

Comment: @TheDestroyer it's not so much about controversy. It's about finding out the date of composition of some holy scriptures and regarding their interpolation.

Comment: [Questions asking whether something is an interpolation are opinion based and not appropriate for this site](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1983/3500) discusses  about interpolations. I think you can ask only for dating of scriptures in this question. IMO, dating of scriptures is impossible. Different historians date differently while traditionalists never accept these dates. So, it is subjective and opinion based. Better if we not allow

Comment: Btw, are you any old user? why you asked this question?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I'm a new user, I wanted to gauge the sensibility of this website so I asked this question. The link you gave says interpolation questions not allowed, but there are many questions on this website asking questions on interpolations

Comment: Any specific questions which you want to ask on dating and interpolations? can you also mention which questions on interpolations you are talking about?

Comment: @TheDestroyer yes but if I make the question public, it may disturb the faith of Hindus. So I'm thinking should I post that or not.

Comment: how can question disturb faith? interpolations and dating techniques can give subjective results. This is reason why such questions can't be allowed.

Comment: @TheDestroyer the dating techniques based on astronomy cannot be subjective. If such questions are not allowed the it's fine, I don't have to make a moral decision.

Comment: @TheDestroyer see if Hindus consider a text to be composed around 3000 BC and then the text says Jesus walked on water, you can be objectively sure the text was composed around after 100 AD. This is not subjective. Either the verse must be interpolated or it must be composed later. Whichever will disturb the people whp believe in the holiness of it

Comment: @Optimus If you're talking about Hindu scriptures like Mahabharat mentioning about Buddha and Buddhism then that does not prove anything regarding the dates of the scriptures ... Because as per Hindu scriptures there are many Buddhas and not just one of them and historians don't have any clues regarding the dates of these ancient Buddhas. And moreover, if you feel something will offend users here then obviously better not to post it. Your other Qs are good and don't offend so continue with such posts.

Comment: @Rickross it's not about Buddhas. And it is not offensive as such, it questions th faith. Its about dating some scriptre which using seasons with lunar months. Which proves beyond doubt that it was a conposed between 1800 BC to 600 AD. And not some 5000 or 10000 years ago which many Hindus believe. The other alternative is to say the text is interpolated.

Comment: So you are the only person who knows the truth and all Hindus on the other side? @Optimus

Comment: @Optimus not like that. Many Hindus do not see these minute details and ignore them. They are more concerned with spirituality and moral values it brings rather than the dating gramar etc.

Comment: @Rickross I actually asked a popular scholar, Nilesh Oak, he said these verses were interpolated.

Comment: Is he a Siddha Purusha? If not how will he say that if some verses are interpolated or not? Only an all knowing person can say such things accurately others can only guess. There are some sites (like History or Sceptic) where spiritual, super natural evidences have no value. It will be better for you to ask on those sites IMO @Optimus

Comment: @Rickross yes but khagola shastra is a part of Hinduism. Anyway I thought it's better not to ask it here as it may disturb faith. See everyone knows Puranas are interpolated just by the evidence of it mentioning certain things. And you see many patterns. For eg. Zodiac signs are not at all mentioned in ancient Hindu scriptures. You can see these patterns. Nilesh Oak is actually trying to say the scriptires are very very old. I'm saying some parts of it is new. The evidence I showed was so powerful he had to say it was interpolated to make it old

Comment: @Rickross also super natural evidences cannot contradict basic logic. That is why ib Indian proof system or Pramana Shastra it is Pratyaksha > Anumana > Agama or Shabdha. So any Agama or Shabdha should not contradict logic. This we follow in the Vedanta

Comment: @Optimus Who said Zodiac is not even mentioned? Ramayana mentions Karka and Meena. Rig Veda has mantras of Dirghatamas which alludes metaphorically to Zodiac. There are already such questions asked on site.

Comment: @TheDestroyer in Rig Veda the number 12 is mentioned. It's the number of full moons or months in a year. Not necessarily the zodiacs with the same signs. I'm asking for earliest mention of zodiacs by name. It's mentioned in Ramayana, because the Ramayana we have today is probably of a later day composition. Infact that was the scripture I wamted to ask about. Other than Ramayana, there is no other ancient scriptire which mentions zodiacs by name, not even Mahabharata. I ask you, to quote any other ancient scriptire which has zodiacs by name.

Comment: @Optimus if you say Ramayana available now is of later age, you can say same to any scripture i present. Anyways, Vedas are terse and highly philosophical. We can't search word "hanuman" in Vedas and say Hanuman is not mentioned in vedas and say he's Puranic deity elevated in later stages. This is done by Scholars and Indologists. Sampradayajnas and Sadhakas understand philosophical verses with intuition developed through sadhana and find Hanuman in Vedas. All finally boils down to approach in which one finds truth. Sampradayic followers don't subscribe to this modern approach.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I don't know what Sampradaya you are talking about. In India we have given Praryaksha and Anumana greatest importance only then comes Shabd praman etc. Shri Adi Shankaracharya says "Even a hundred statements of sruti to the effect that fire is cold and non-luminous won't prove valid. If it does make such a statement, its import will have to be interpreted differently" This is our Sampradaya. Ramayana mentions zodiac. Which no other ancient scripture mentions. Now in Ramayana it is said Rainy season Starts with Shravana month, this possible only from 1500 BC to 500 AD.

Comment: @TheDestroyer no I can't say the same thing about any scripture you present, for Vedas if we use the same technique then we get 3000 BC.

Comment: @Optimus So, how do you prove Swarga and Naraka exist? how do you prove rebirth exists with pratyaskha? They don't exist and should be rejected? people who do Yajnas see devatas taking havis? So, we should stop doing Yajnas? Nala only could see Devatas taking Havis as part of boon he got from devatas. So, people like him only should give havis as our "eyes" are pramana? Ramayana statement you said is subjected to interpretation. Why stopping at 1500 BC? why not it be a  multiples of 26,000 to that number? this is what happens when you follow modern scientific approach..(1/n)

Comment: @Optimus which believes in empirical evidence to prove things mentioned in scriptures. Shastras don't say fire is hot as they don't talk about sensory truths. Rishis say truths that are beyond mind, senses and intellect. Prajna is Ritambara. Change Pramana and everything makes sense. (2/n)

Comment: @TheDestroyer bro, you don't know how Pramana works. Whatever is proven by Pratyaksha is ultimate. What pratyaksha cannot prove or is silent, Anumana works there. Where Anumana or Logic cannot say anything there Shabda pramana works. Do you get this? Swarga, Naraka, Yajna all these are extra sensory as you said, so Shastra is pramana there. Correct. Bit Seasons, Nakshatras, History etc is not extra sensory. So it falls under Pratyaksha amd Anumana. You can't compare rainy season with Swarga and Karma and Ritambhara. (1/n)

Comment: @TheDestroyer now you can try to make it multiple of 26000 years but then there was simply no language developed or civilizations like Ramayana by 26000 BC. This is not extra sensory truth. This is archealogical, historical truth.(2/n)

Comment: @Optimus No i do know how Pramana works. Pratyaksha doesn't just mean information known through senses. It is also Jnana known through intuition. Don't miss this. Obviously Pratyaksha is ultimate. Pratyaksha jnana of Rishis through inner experience becomes Shabda Pramana later.  Unless you become Rishi/jivanmukta, some answers are not known. Pramana of Archeology, Indology, history is not correct Pratyaksha.

Comment: @TheDestroyer bro the Pratyaksha of Rishis is pratyaksha for them, not for you. For you it is still Shabda. Indology is different, it's social and political narration. But Archeology, Astronomy, Evolution and Human History are Pratyaksha and Anumana. They are superior to Shabda if there is dorect contradiction. I'm not saying Ramayana itself is wrong. It's true, it is mentioned in Mahabharata. But the current version we habe mayhave been highly interpolated or maybe of a later origin. Do you know how much interpolation is done in Puranas?? Jesus and Mohammed are there.

Comment: @TheDestroyer you called my older answer rude. I have edited it. But was I wrong? One can see easily that we Hindus are celebrating Uttarayana and Dakshinayana wrong. You'll argue with NASA? Many festivals tied with seasons are all out of sync. But people are continuing this.

Comment: @Optimus Will end this discussion and not drag this. Pratyaksha of Rishis can be verified only if we go that state of Rishi. No Archeology, evolution, Astrology can help. And, logic is also subjective, Logic depends on knowledge and Prajna of a person. A person with no deep knowledge in philosophy/tattva can feel many things as illogical. So, proper approach to verify scriptures is to go to state of  Rishis and verify in direct experience. Archeology, Evolution will not prove Rishis vakyas. Interpolation is again different subject. discussion will prolong if i discuss this topic.

Comment: @TheDestroyer you are free to believe whatever you want. Our ancients, the Rishis you spoke about have clearly said first Pratyaksha, then Anumana and then Shabda. Science is Pratyaksha and Anumana. This is what Rishis say. Evolution is a fact based on Anumana. Which is what our Rishis have used. Anyway people can believe what they want

Comment: @TheDestroyer you even Hindus are correct with Uttarayana and festivals?? Also where is Hanuman in Vedas. This is the first time I'm reading about this. Why would Hanuman be there as it was composed before and where is it written, like I'm curious about it.

Comment: @Optimus Green, we already discussed on same topics in past. no need to repeat again.

Comment: While logical reasoning is (and has long historically been) a widely-accepted pramana, there are many users here who blindly follow without understanding such things. So, as someone who has gone through this before, several times, be aware that some people will downvote such questions without leaving any response as to why. Others might give a reason, but do not respond well a reply they perceive as threatening to their dug-in beliefs. So, while this IS the best forum for those who sincerely want to understand things better, it is also very frustrating for those same people. Be so advised.

Comment: Full disclosure: I read the question, not the entire reply thread. Apologies if I repeated someone

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no contradiction between the 3 statements. Simple boolean logic will solve your confusion.

Manu :

1. Speak Truth
2. Speak Love
3. But do not speak false love
4. And do not speak hate truth

Bharavi :

1. Well wishers do not speak false love

Upanishad :

1. Speak Truth

Let me ask you a question - How much money is in your bank account ?

If you follow "Truth" doctrine you have to tell everyone. You cannot lie and you cannot hide. Right ?

Wrong. Keeping quiet is not a lie. So it will not break the "Truth" doctrine.

So, the resolution to the apparent contradiction is :

- If what you are speaking is both true AND love, speak it.
- If any of the above is absent (NOT true OR NOT love), keep silent.