# Is this site suffering from religious chauvinism?

Tags: discussion, scope, code-of-conduct

A recent question on the MAINS gets 10 Upvotes. This is the question: [Do all Non-Hindus remain as Pretas after death?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45560/do-all-non-hindus-remain-as-pretas-after-death)

Now, I want to ask, why should this site reconcile with any question related with people or things who aren't Hindu? Maybe sometimes a comparative analysis of few things maybe done. that too on a discussion and prescriptive form basis. But, asking on behalf of the other religions by applying our own logic and beliefs is certainly and unequivocally a detestable, outlandish and preposterous act.

**ONE MIGHT NEED TO HAVE A GOOD LOOK AT THIS AGAIN:** [Need to take down abysmal posts from the main site](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/need-to-take-down-abysmal-posts-from-the-main-site/2102#2102).

The raised question in all ways should belong to the abysmal category.

What's more surprising and idiosyncratic (of course!! ), is it got a good 10 Upvotes, and an answer too. With still no chance of Being closed ASAP (only two closed votes), It certainly points out to a presence of complex to justify everything by our own faith and systems. A typical example of what psychology call as - the Inferiority Complex.

Are we suffering from some form of religious chauvinism or inferiority complex, to bring and try to compare with, the paradigm of other faiths with ours? Why hasn't any action being taken against this kind of content?

I'd please like to request the MODS, to take appropriate action against these kinds of question and especially on a fast track basis at-least for this question, which incite answers on behalf of faiths irrelevant to our Hinduism.

This is really unbelievable and certainly in no way a sign of a professional and cultured community. This kind of content shouldn't belong to SE.

Comment: As one old time user sv keeps reminding us, this site is not just limited to Hindus but also caters to non-Hindus. So I don't see why it is a problem if questions pertaining to Hinduism are framed in this manner

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *This is really unbelievable and certainly in no way a sign of a professional and cultured community. This kind of content shouldn't belong to SE.*

Although your intentions for disallowing such questions on SE seem genuine, other SE sites for religions have allowed similar questions purely from a scholarly standpoint:

- [Do non-Christians go to hell?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75527/do-non-christians-go-to-hell)
- [If a non-Muslim is a great person, He fulfills everyone rights so still will he go to hell after dying as he is a non-Muslim?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50885/if-a-non-muslim-is-a-great-person-he-fulfills-everyone-rights-so-still-will-he)

From around the net:

- [The Fate of Non-Muslims: Perspectives on Salvation Outside of Islam](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/jonathan-brown/the-fate-of-non-muslims-perspectives-on-salvation-outside-of-islam)
- [According to Islam, are all non-Muslims going to hell?](https://www.alislam.org/question/islam-all-non-muslims-going-to-hell/)

As long as a question can be answered using Hindu scriptures/commentaries and asked in a manner that doesn't break the [CoC](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct), I think we should allow them. However, this is only possible if users can remain detached from the question, stop attributing motives to OP, stop speculating how such Q&A are perceived by society at large and only look at the question from an answerability point.

Answer (score 6):

Truth does not care about inferiority, superiority or equality complex.

If our scriptures say Preta Samskara needs to be done, that's it.

There is no need to sugarcoat the response in order to seem "non-inferiority-complex-y".

That being said, animals also die and no Vedic samskara is done for them. So I personally don't think Preta Samskara according to Hindu mantras is necessary for ALL types of beings, in order for them to move on to the next life/wherever.

If someone counters my above stance with *"How dare you compare non-Hindus to animals?"*, I will respond with *"How dare you imply that animals are lesser beings.. are you suffering from human-chauvinism?"*

Comment: Certain self-appointed flag-bearers of Hindu dharma don't understand the difference between upholding hindu dharma and popularity contests @SK

Comment: Google assigns a quality score to websites and they have sophisticated algorithms to come up with relevance and qualiy scores for webpages/websites. If the aim of HSE is to rank among top search results for Hinduism related topics - non-serious posts do not help. This might have direct ad-revenue implications for SE in the future. SE is serious, having so kindly provided this beautiful platform for free. Hinduism is serious. Making HSE a quality site is something we should all take seriously..

Comment: That was very evident when you implicated, "cats don't understand sanskrit" statement in a "fantastic" question of yours. So, I'm very sure, what ideology it might connotes to. Not a big difference from the other kinds of "peace faiths".

Comment: @Vivikta - i have no desire to differentiate our faith from the Abrahamics. If two people claim their path is the best, should one group give up its claim to be different from the other ? Each religion's path is the best for its followers. Which path they choose depends on which religion suits them.

Comment: @Vivikta I think a lot of people have misinterpreted my question. What I meant by this question was whether or not the Jivatmas of non-Hindus, which turn Preta, remain so for a much longer period of time than Hindus, thereby having to avoid the normal process of departing for Yamaloka, on the 11th or whichever day. Nowhere did I want to imply that the Jivatmas of non-Hindus remain stuck as Pretas without having any more births in the future.

Comment: @learner, I have nothing against you on a personal level. Whatever your motif was with asking that question is irrelevant. The question raised by me is why noone seems to be perturbed with questions not about Hinduism. Why anyone needs to have a POV about anyone but Hindus? The question should have been closed, had it been a professional cultured, rules following community. But, this seriously seems to suggest that a whole zealot gang works, along with explicit MODS support to undermine this beautiful platform, SE Network has provided us with., thus disregarding all kinds of Code of Conduct.

Comment: @Vivikta, my question involves seeing and understanding other things (non-Hindus) from a Hindu perspective. Yes; it does not have anything to do with Hindus, themselves. But similar questions exist on HSE. On HSE, there are questions about whether Hindus should marry foreigners (to which, the answers cite scriptures that refer to non-Hindus as mlechchas). However, my question did not suggest anything offensive or include derogatory words, or any uncouth language.